# If p (mod 4) = 3 and p is a Gaussian Prime. How to show that Z[i]/(p) is equal to GF(p^2)/(x^2+1)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, elliptic-curves, gaussian-integers

I currently work with Gaussian Integer. I try to use prime Gaussian Integer field for Elliptic Curve instead of prime field.
.
We know that every finite field isomorphic to polynomial field with modulus irreducible polynomial and all finite fields of the same size are isomorphic.
.
When I counting the order of the elliptic curve group, I found that *Z[i]/(p)* and *GF(p^2)/(x^2+1)* give the same output (same order).
But if I change the modulus with another irreducible polynomial, the output is not same.
.
Why? Is any special thing that I missed?
.
Thankyou, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What does $x$ mean in $GF(p^2)/(x^2+1) $?

Comment: What is $GF(p^2)$?

Comment: The letters GF stand for "Galois field". *x* in *GF(p^2)/(x^2+1)* is variable in polynomial *x^2+1*

Comment: *GF(p^2)* is a field that have *p^2* elements.

Comment: Do you mean $GF(p^2)[x]/(x^2+1)$ or $GF(p)[x]/(x^2+1)$?

Comment: The first one, field that have p^2 elements

Answer (score 2):

(This is a late answer, just found this question while looking for something specific related to elliptic curves.)

We have the sequence of isomorphisms of rings / fields. (I will use $=$ instead of $\cong$ to mark isomorphic objects, thus working the corresponding category.)
I will also use the notation $\Bbb F_q$ for "the" field with $q$ elements instead of $GF(q)$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb Z[i]/p
&=(\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2+1))\ /\ (p)\\
&=\Bbb Z[x]\ /\ (x^2+1,\ p)\\
&=(\Bbb Z[x]/(p))\ /\ (x^2+1)\\
&=\Bbb F_p[x]\ /\ (x^2+1)\\
&=\Bbb F_{p^2}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where at the last step we use $p=-1$ modulo four, so that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$, i.e. $(x^2+1)$ has no roots in $\Bbb F_p$, i.e. it is an irreducible = prime polynomial.

---

Let $i$ be the class of $x$ in the field $\Bbb F_{q}$, $q=p^2$, obtained above, so $i^2=-1$.

Then note that $GF(p^2)[y]/(y^2+1)$ is not a field, since the polynomial $y^2+1=(y+i)(y-i)$ splits in two factors over $GF(p^2)=GF(q)=\Bbb F_q$. This is related to the question of Ihf in the comments. The field with $q=p^2$ elements is the one mentioned in the above chain at forelast place, $\Bbb F_p[x]\ /\ (x^2+1)$.